# Can we Use Django GraphQL JWT For authentification and also Django rest framework for other apis together?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

1. I feel very difficult to cover DRF_jwt/DRF_oauth2 but Django GraphQL
   JWT seems easy....
2. Can i use both of them together for my ease
3. I am new in Rest Framework

Answer (score 1):

If you mean using django-graphql-jwt to authentication and using DRF for other user account related actions, like updating, retrieving, deleting, reset password...

You can use [django-graphql-auth](https://django-graphql-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

It extends django-graphql-jwt, and provide a full api to handle user account.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom authentication backend for **DRF** that extends `rest_framework.authentication.BaseAuthentication` and uses `graphql_jwt.utils` to authenticate the user in **DRF** the exact same way `django-graphql-jwt` does it.

This is what I have:

```py
from graphql_jwt.exceptions import JSONWebTokenError
from graphql_jwt.utils import get_payload, get_user_by_payload
from rest_framework.authentication import BaseAuthentication, get_authorization_header
from rest_framework import exceptions


class TokenAuthentication(BaseAuthentication):
    keyword = 'JWT'

    def authenticate(self, request):
        auth = get_authorization_header(request).split()

        if not auth or auth[0].lower() != self.keyword.lower().encode():
            return None

        if len(auth) == 1:
            msg = 'Invalid token header. No credentials provided.'
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)
        elif len(auth) > 2:
            msg = 'Invalid token header. Token string should not contain spaces.'
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)

        try:
            token = auth[1].decode()
        except UnicodeError:
            msg = 'Invalid token header. Token string should not contain invalid characters.'
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)

        try:
            payload = get_payload(token)
            user = get_user_by_payload(payload)
        except JSONWebTokenError as e:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(str(e))

        if user is None or not user.is_active:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('User inactive or deleted.')

        return (user, None)

    def authenticate_header(self, request):
        return self.keyword
```